# How to count non-alphanumeric characters on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, text, feature-extraction, non-alphanumeric

Here's my data

```
No  Body
1   DaTa, Analytics 2
2   StackOver. 67%
```

Here's my expected output

```
No  Body                 Non Alphanumeric   
1   DaTa, Analytics 2    1       
2   StackOver. 67%       2
```

I am only count non-alphanumeric like `! @ # & ( ) % – [ { } ] : ; ', ? / *`  space and number is not count

Comment: In first string are double whitepaces, `,` and `2` so count is `4`. What need count?

Comment: Any non-alphanumeric  `! @ # & ( ) % – [ { } ] : ; ', ? / *` , `2`, space is not count

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['Non Alphanumeric'] = df['Body'].str.findall(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]').str.len()
```

Or:

```
df['Non Alphanumeric'] = df['Body'].str.count(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]')

print (df)
   No               Body  Non Alphanumeric
0   1  DaTa, Analytics 2                 1
1   2     StackOver. 67%                 2
```